# MySQL Login Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a MySQL database that is hosted by paralell plesk and I am trying to connect using Visual Basic.  Currently every time I try to connect I get the following error

> Authentication to host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' for user 'myuser' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'My public IP address' (using password: NO)

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class SQLControl
    Private SQLCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=50.62.209.150 ; user id=root ;password=; database=mytestdb;")
    Private SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
    Public SQLDA As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public SQLDS As DataSet

    Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCon.Close()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()

            ' Create Command
            SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

            ' Fill Dataset
            SQLDA = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            SQLDS = New DataSet
            SQLDA.Fill(SQLDS)

            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            ' Make sure connection is Closed
            If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: you need to allow access from your IP.

See this page: http://kb.parallels.com/en/1134 for more information

Comment: the other thing is, im using plesk as a web hosting service that i purchased so i dont know how to access the config file

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty obvious: `Server=50.62.209.150 ; user id=root ;password=`

you are trying to connect to a public server with root user and without a password. While this is possible to configure, this would allow anyone to connect and your server would be hacked within minutes.

Just read the mysql docs about user account management http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.1/en/user-account-management.html and you should be able to solve your issue.

The best thing would be to create a dedicated user with limited rights. If you want to connect from a fixed ip address you can even limit the user to your ip (`user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`)

Comment: Yes, but i cant even login with "user id=root ; password=" it wont let me the same error occurs...

Comment: MySQL allows to configure access based on ip-addresses. So you can allow `user@127.0.0.1` (which is the local host) and `user@192.168.178.10` to login but deny login from any other host. To allow login from any host you have to create a user `user@%`.
In your setup the user `root` is not allowed to connect from any host without a pasword which is a good thing.